# How to Set Input Filter Programmaticlly in BCS

Tags: 2010, bcs

I have a `Method` in `Entity` which takes 2 input filters. Now I want to set a value in this filter. How can I do that? I already got the collection of Filters using the `GetFilters()` method of the `MethodInstance` object. I found code that shows how to set other filters, but I don't know how to set input filters.

Please advise

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks Guys,I got it working here is code how to do it 
 IFilterCollection filters = mi.GetFilters();
                    //IParameterCollection parameters = mi.GetMethod().GetParameters();
                    IUserInputFilter wsIdfiler = filters[0] as IUserInputFilter;
                    wsIdfiler[0] = 0;
                    IUserInputFilter docIdFilter = filters1 as IUserInputFilter;
                    docIdFilter[0] = 12345;

and here is link i get information from 
http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-AU/sharepoint2010programming/thread/b9042288-ba0f-47e9-a1cf-6565964d227b

Thanks 
Ronak